# calling functions with user input and while loops

Tags: python-3.x

thank you for your answers, I have since changed it a bit but keen getting an infinite loop. when the user enters option 1-5 inclusive it moves on, but if the user enters 6 or more it will keep asking for a valid option (1-5), but when this runs, even when i give an option from 1-5 it keeps saying it is invalid.

```
def get_user_input(): 
    user_input = int(input("Enter your choice: ")) 
    while user_input > 5: 
        print("Invalid menu option.") 
        int(input("Please try again: ")) 
    if user_input <= 5: 
        return user_input
```

Comment: Can you format your code? This is not proper python and doesn't run.

Comment: Please fix your indentation, explain what you're trying to do, and what error you're getting. See [ask] for tips.

Comment: thank you for your answers, I have since changed it a bit but keen getting an infinite loop. when the user enters option 1-5 inclusive it moves on, but if the user enters 6 or more it will keep asking for a valid option (1-5), but when this runs, even when i give an option from 1-5 it keeps saying it is invalid.     

    def get_user_input():

        user_input = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

        while user_input > 5:
            print("Invalid menu option.")
            int(input("Please try again: "))
    
            if user_input <= 5:
    
                return user_input

Comment: You need to reassign the value read in the loop to `user_input`....... And you're still missing proper indentation.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the indent and it works now after user_input was assigned in the loop

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you're requesting a new user input, but not doing anything with it. You need to assign the new input to your `user_input` variable which is being tested in the loop condition:

```
def get_user_input(): 
    user_input = int(input("Enter your choice: ")) 
    while user_input > 5: 
        print("Invalid menu option.") 
        user_input = int(input("Please try again: "))   ### add the assignment on this line!
    return user_input   ### no if needed here, return unconditionally
```

I've also removed the `if` line from after the loop. If you successfully exited the loop, the input is already known to be less than `5` so there's no need to check that again.